# Different cases for "Couldn't resolve reference" in Xtext, particularly solved, but how about an attribute reference?

Tags: reference, xtext

I have the following Xtext grammar part:

```
AssignmentStatement: (variable=[SymbolicVariable] | array=ArrayVariable) ':=' value=Expression;
ArrayVariable: varName=[SymbolicVariable] '[' index=Expression ']';
SymbolicVariable: name=ID;
```

and a test where id1 and id2 are SymbolicVariable, moreover  SymbolicVariable can be part of Expression:

```
id1 := 0 < id2 [ 0 ]
```

In the test, id1 and id2 are not defined before since I am generating inputs as tests by the grammar and do not care on semantics. I want to create objects for them dynamically to get rid of:

> ERROR:Couldn't resolve reference to SymbolicVariable 'id1'.

> ERROR:Couldn't resolve reference to SymbolicVariable 'id2'.

while validation.

Following the ideas from post [XText cross-reference to an non-DSL resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365891/xtext-cross-reference-to-an-non-dsl-resource), I was able to create a ScopeProvider impl as well as a Scope impl:

```
class MyScope extends AbstractPoSTScopeProvider {
    
    override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
        val res = context.eResource
        var uri = res.URI       
        val rs = res.resourceSet
        val scope = super.getScope(context, reference)
        if (context instanceof ArrayVariableImpl) new ScopeWrapper(scope, res) else scope
    }
}

class ScopeWrapper implements IScope {
    
    IScope scope;
    Resource resource;
    
    protected new(IScope w, Resource res) {
        scope = w
        resource = res
    }
    override getSingleElement(QualifiedName name) {
        println("[scope]getSingleElement " + name.toString())
        val r = scope.getSingleElement(name)
        if (r === null) {
            val fac = PoSTPackage.eINSTANCE.getPoSTFactory()
            var s = fac.createSymbolicVariable()
            s.name = name.toString()
            println("[!!!!! ] creation")
            Main.isChanged = true //to rerun in cause of modification 
            val ret = new MyDescr(s, name) //just a wrap
            resource.contents += s
            ret
        } else
        r
    }
    
}
```

After this injection, id2 is appeared and I can generate a code with it, but I still get

> ERROR:Couldn't resolve reference to SymbolicVariable 'id1'.

and I do not see id1 anywhere during the debug.

Seems, for attributes we need some other magic.
Which pattern should I follow?

Answer (score 1):

> In the test, id1 and id2 are not defined before since I am generating inputs as tests by the grammar and do not care on semantics.

If you are generating your textual model `id1 := 0 < id2 [ 0 ]`, I am not sure why you could not generate it as `id1; id2; id1 := 0 < id2 [ 0 ]` which would probably resolve OK.

If you really want to "create id1 and id2 dynamically", I think you need to customize your `IScopeProvider` implementation such that when computing the scopes for both references `AssignmentStatement.variable` and `ArrayVariable.varName`, if the parent implementation returns an empty scope, then you simply create a `SymbolicVariable` in memory and provide it in the returned scope.